# Как в Java найти MinGrade через итератор?

Tags: java

```
public static int getMinGrade(ArrayList<Student> arrayList)  {

    int min = arrayList.get(0).getGrade();
    Iterator<Student> i = arrayList.listIterator();
    for (int d = 1; i.hasNext(); d++)
    {
        if (arrayList.get(d).getGrade() < min)
        {
            min = arrayList.get(d).getGrade();
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Ошибка в том, что `i.hasNext()` выходит за предел массива. Но как исправить его? По заданию нужно использовать итератор, чтобы найти минимальную оценку элементов. `arrayList.size()` использовать нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int getMinGrade(ArrayList<Student> arrayList) {
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    Iterator<Student> i = arrayList.listIterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        int grade = i.next().getGrade();
        if (grade < min) {
            min = grade;
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```